# Getting values from Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql, session-variables

I have this piece of code

```
var myList = (from p in db.Full
              where ((p.date_reception > begin & p.date_reception < end & !p.mc_host_class.Contains("NULL")) &
                    (!strListe.Contains(p.mc_host_class)))
              group p by p.mc_host_class into g
              orderby g.Count() descending
              select new
              {
                  hostclassx = g.Key,
                  countx = g.Count()
              }).Take(10).ToList();           

HttpContext.Current.Session["allList"] = myList;
```

i want to get two type of values from my session variable , before using session variable i used to do

```
object[] ys = myList.Select(a => (object)a.countx.ToString()).ToArray();
List<String> xs = new List<string>();

foreach (var x in myList.Select(i => i.hostclassx))
{
        xs.Add(x);
}
```

I want to get the same type of variables(xs and ys) from my session variable

Comment: Did you mean to use the [_logical AND_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) operator `&&` instead of the [_binary AND_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) operator `&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stored an anonymous object inside the session. Anonymous objects are not intended to be leaving the boundaries of the current method. So start by defining a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string HostClass { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and then project your query into this object (bear in mind that you might need to adjust the type of the `HostClass` property according to your needs - I have defined it as a string but in your particular model it might be some other type, it's just not clear what types of objects are involved in your queries from the code you have pasted so far):

```
...
orderby g.Count() descending
select new MyModel
{
    HostClass = g.Key,
    Count = g.Count()
}).Take(10).ToList();
```

Alright, now you've got a `List<MyObject>` stored inside your `Session["allList"]`. So in order to retrieve this value somewhere else in your code it's just a matter of casting back to this same type:

```
var list = (List<MyModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["allList"];
```

And as a side note you seem to be using a `&` operator instead of `&&` in your where predicates, maybe you didn't exactly wanted to use this. You seem to be confusing the `logical AND` operator and the `binary AND` operator.

Comment: Thank you that worked fine but how to deal with the object[]  type

Comment: Why are you using weakly typed `object[]`? Directly use the exact type form the model.

Comment: I'm using dotnetHighcharts that requires object[] type in the Y axe.

Comment: Alright great, but how is this related to your original question about the session?

Comment: I said "I want to get the same type of variables(xs and ys) from my session variable"

Comment: I am not quite sure what `xs` and `ys` variables you are talking about. You wrote a LINQ query and projected this query to a custom model. Adapt your model with the correct types so that you get the same values back when you cast to `List<MyModel>`.